# How to count the distinct values repeated in table

Tags: php, sql

I have a table which has columns as id | BSC | Size .Now each column has some data in it like

```
       id |   BSC     |  Size

       1    Tambaram     100
       2    Tambaram     200
       3    Perungudi    100
       4    Tambaram     100
       5    Perungudi    200
```

I want to find the count of the number of distinct values and how many times each of those distinct values are repeated like 100 is repeated 3 times and 200 for 2 times.
I have used COUNT and DISTINCT and getting the count of the number of distinct values. But i also want to know how many times those are repeated.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if (!$link)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
  }
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Size) FROM Query_count");
if($result){
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $data[0];
}
$link->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `group by` like

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Size) as sizes
FROM Query_count
GROUP BY BSC
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how many time single SIZE values are present you shuold use

```
SELECT SIZE, COUNT(*) AS RN
FROM QUERY_COUNT
GROUP BY SIZE
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing group by size:

```
SELECT size, count(*) as count from Query_count
GROUP BY size
```